# Catching real cause of android reboot

Tags: reboot

I am currently using my phone with CM installed (newest release, clean install). For some reason the phone keeps rebooting at random moments, when sleeping (never when awake). 
I wonder if it is possible to find out the **real** reason of rebooting, other than checking /proc/last_kmsg: for me, it only states if it was caused by unsecure-watchdog-bite, or kernel panic. I am curious about finding out, which process' irresponsiveness caused the watchdog-bite, or what made the kernel panic.

Details:
Moto G xt1032, newest firmware
CM13.0, release ZNH5Y
recovery: twrp 3.0.2

Tl;dr: last kernel message is not informative enough about last restart reason.

Edit: link to kernel messages: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AqQWXVmn2ZoKonIJgnToo58XmoVy

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `adb logcat` command from the `terminal/command prompt` to examine continuously your device log. On your device has to be enabled `USB debugging` in `Settings -> Developer options` section.

Or after the random reboot try

```
su  
cat /proc/last_kmsg > /mnt/sdcard/last_kmsg
```

from a terminal window on your device. You can [download terminal app from Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=terminal&utm_source=opensearch).

For the `su` command your device has to be rooted.

Comment: I have been exactly using your latter solution to map kernel messages. I edited my main comment to add some links to kernel messages.